# PyTorch Lightning auto_scale_batch_size='power' does not show results

Tags: pytorch-lightning

I am very new to Deep Learning, and am converting an [existing project](https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning) into a Pytorch Lightning one following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHww1JH7IDU).

I want to try the [automatic batch size finder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlK7VVdzsSI). So I added the requested flag to the `Trainer` :

```
trainer = pl.Trainer(default_root_dir=model_dir, 
                     auto_scale_batch_size='power')
```

and also added a `batch_size` parameter to the model's **init** method that is then used with `self.batch_size = batch_size`.

```
class MyModel(pl.LightningModule):
  def __init__(self, other params, batch_size)
     super().__init__()
     self.batch_size = batch_size
```

In `train_dataloader` I also use this `self.batch_size` :

```
train_loader = DataLoader(self.dataset,
                             collate_fn=lambda batch: collate_synthesizer(batch, self.reduction_factor, self.hparams2),
                             batch_size=self.batch_size,
                             num_workers=self.num_workers if platform.system() != "Windows" else 0,
                             shuffle=True,
                             pin_memory=True)
```

But the training process runs without showing anything special about its findings with regards to batch_size. I tried it on my dev laptop (cpu mode) and on colab (gpu) without seeing anything.

Should I wait till the end of the process or I missed something ?

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I missed something in the video that I later found in the [doc](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/training_tricks.html#auto-scaling-of-batch-size). I was calling `trainer.fit(model)` instead of `trainer.tune(model)`. Now it is working great!